# CSS Resizing with % - Offset

Tags: css, cross-browser, offset

So I have a floating div, and I need it to always be 200px to the right, and fill the rest of the window. Is there some way that is cross browser compatible that I can make the width fill the rest of the page without resorting to javascript?

Comment: Floating meaning using `float`? Or being absolutely positioned?

Comment: Could you put your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX7vd/)

All you must do is specify how far to the right you want it bumped by setting a `margin-left`, then use `display:block` to make it take up the rest of the width.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have to add the 200px margin to the parent of the div, so you have to introduce a container as illustrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/4ywP3/). Note that the width's percentage now is based on the nett width of the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `left` and `right` CSS for the element you can specify to always have the `<div>` be 200px narrower than it's parent element.

```
#its_a_div {
    position   : absolute;
    right      : 200px;
    left       : 0px;
    height     : 100px;
}
```

A jsfiddle for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/F8g2q/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand than you want correctly (to have block in the beginning of the content align to the right for 200px width content flow around it), the you can do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/yD49z/1/

Works for me in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Didn't test in IE through, don't have access to one right now.